# Unable to start terminal on PyCharm on Ubuntu

Tags: pycharm, ioexception

I wanted to run a code, and for that, I installed PyCharm on my Ubuntu Machine. Now. When I opened the PyCharm application and tried to open the terminal, it throws an error and doesn't open the terminal.

> java.io.IOException: Exec_tty error:Unknown pycharm

Additional Notes: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on VMware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set your shell path. You could use `cat /etc/shells` command to see where you shell is then set it in PyCharm
`Preferences` `>` `Tools` `>` `Terminal` `>` `Shell path`.