# CLion Terminal Exception on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, clion

I'm on `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` with `VMWare Workstation 15 Player` and when trying to open the `Terminal` in `CLion 2018.2.5` I'm getting the following error message:

```
Can't Open Local Terminal
java.io.IOException: Exec_tty error:Unknown reason
```

[image]

Here are my `Terminal` settings in `CLion`:

[image]

The `Bash` shell is selected by default and independently from `CLion` it obviously works fine hence [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43629997/3764804) doesn't work. Also apparently [the bug has been fixed](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203368470-Alternative-terminal-crashing) but I'm still running into it now.

How can this problem be fixed so I can use the `CLion` internal `Terminal` as well?

Comment: Does bash work on a normal Terminal? does /mnt/hgfs/D/ exist?

Comment: @arved: Yes to both. `/mnt/hgfs/D/` is a shared folder from the host OS (Windows 10).